# Pass URL to webview Android from Firebase Push Notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am able to send push notification to and app with key value pair.

How to give the value as URL and when the user clicks on the notification received, it must navigate to a webview with the URL mentioned in the data value from Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Create intent to your Activity with webview

```
intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("url", your_url_from_data);
```

Create Content intent

```
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, getNotificationID(), intent ,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

`setContentIntent(contentIntent)` in notification builder

Then in WebViewActivity.class just receive url from bundle and load to webview as `webView.loadUrl(url)`

Comment: If you are sending these notifications from the Firebase Console, be sure to check that your logic works when the app is in the background, as the notification that gets triggered when the app is in the background will be automatically created by Firebase, and you wont be able to set a custom PendingIntent. If you want this to work reliably, you need to implement data messages https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages