# Android reload WebView URL onNewToken from Firebase Messaging Center

Tags: java, android, firebase, webview

I'm running a WebView Android App that points to a WebApp. Everything ok. But now, I'm having problem to refresh the url which is already loaded when the method `onNewToken` from `FirebaseMessagingService` is called and also inject a JS into it. I have heard about `Intents` and also found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477922/pass-url-to-webview-android-from-firebase-push-notification) but can't really understand how and where to apply the `Intents`.

Here is what my code currently looks like:

**MyFirebaseMessagingService**:

```java
package com.example.app;

import android.util.Log;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMessagingService";

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
        // I want to call the loadUrl here using a injected JS to send the token to the Web App
    }
}
```

**MyWebViewClient**:

```java
package com.example.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    private static final String TAG = "MyWebViewClient";

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        String hostname;

        // YOUR HOSTNAME
        hostname = "192.168.0.11";

        final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
        Log.i(TAG, "Uri =" + uri);
        if (uri.getHost() != null && uri.getHost().endsWith(hostname)) {
            return false;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**:

```java
package com.example.app;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        // REMOTE RESOURCE
         mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.11:3000/");

        // LOCAL RESOURCE
        // mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to use Intents but at first use LocalBroadcastManager in your "MyFirebaseMessagingService" :

```
public static String REQUEST_ACCEPT="action.my.messaging";

@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
    //after any refresh you will notice it to your activity (or fragment)
    Intent intent = new Intent(REQUEST_ACCEPT);
    intent.putExtra("key", "Any Extra Value Here");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getBaseContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    //Or use it here after any message received
}
```

Then in your activity you can receive any notices and do the refresh or any action you want:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // registering an observer (mMessageReceiver) to receive Intents
    // with actions named as the value of REQUEST_ACCEPT.
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(MyFirebaseMessagingService.REQUEST_ACCEPT));
}

// Our handler for received Intents. This will be called whenever an Intent
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get extra data included in the Intent
        String value = intent.getStringExtra("key");
        Log.d(TAG, "Got noticed: " + value );
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! :) as I'm not an Android Dev, I have done this WebApp, it's a bit difficult to get it fast. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome and I wish luck for you :)